# How do I view inbound requests in Azure?

Tags: azure

I want to see ip addresses of all inbound requests to my static website. I believe Azure activity logs exclude GET requests. Is there any way to see everything?

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log) is a type of a [platform log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/platform-logs-overview) in Azure that provides insight into subscription-level events, and not application logs. If you want to collect and monitor [usage statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-overview) for your web application, you should instrument it with [Azure Application Inisghts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview).

That said, note that the Application Insights telemetry module only temporarily collects the client IP address. Once the relevant fields like `client_City`, `client_CountryOrRegion` etc. are populated, the address is then discarded and `0.0.0.0` is written to the client_IP field. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection?tabs=net) article for more details.